# How to pull across data from a collection view cell to a different view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

I've got a collection view with multiple cells in. When the user clicks on the cell it segues to a different view controller. How do I insert the image of that cell the user has clicked on to the new view controller?

I've tried this in the main view controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc =   storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier: "FoodDetailViewController") as? FoodDetailViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true )
}
```

And this is the code for the Detail segue:

```
class FoodDetailViewController: UIViewController {

var recipe: Recipe!
var text: String!
var body: String!


@IBOutlet weak var foodImage: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = recipe.name

}

private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.image = UIImage(named: "PP grey")
    return view
}()

var image: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier: "FoodDetailViewController") as! FoodDetailViewController
vc.recipe = recipes[indexPath.item] // assign property here
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

> Note: using pushViewController has nothing to do with segues , if you want to use a segue then override prepeareForReuse method and set the data to the destination vc

Answer (score 0):

In collectioView `didSelectItemAt` Method, you just need to get the SELECTED cell and then get the Image from that Cell and SImply pass it to NEXT ViewController.

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let cell-image = cell?.IMAGEVIEW.image

        let vc =   storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier: "FoodDetailViewController") as? FoodDetailViewController
        vc.image = cell-image
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true )
   }


   class FoodDetailViewController: UIViewController {
       var image: UIImage?
   }
```

Comment: I'm using a collection view with both horizontal and vertical scroll enabled using sub collection views and child view controllers therefore there isn't a particular cell I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add a segue in the storyboard and override the function `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` and in it you need to setup your FoodDetails with the recipe you need. Do something like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   // you need to identify your segue in the storyboard 
   if segue.identifier == "GoToFoodDetails" {
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? FoodDetailViewController {
            viewController.recipe = selectedRecipe
        }
    }
}
```

For selected recipe you can make a variable and set when you click a recipe using `didSelectItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedRecipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToFoodDetails", sender: self)
}
```